# error "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]" in c++

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with my code. I'm trying to make a program that converts non integer numbers into binary. It returns an error in line 21 saying "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]".
What does this mean and how can I solve it?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string number;

    cout<<"Insert number";
    cin>>number;
    int continue = 0, integer;
    bool first = false;
    while(continue >= 0){
        if(primo == false){
            integer = number[continue];
            first = true;
            continue++;
        }
        else{
            char dot = "."; //line 21
            char comma = ",";
            char check = number[continue];
            if((check == comma) or (check == dot)){
                continue = -1;
            }
            else{
                int encapsulation = number[continue]
                integer = (integer*10)+encapsulation;
                continue++;
            }


        }


    }
    cout<<integer;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char dot = "."; ` you have used the wrong quotation marks for a char. It should be `char dot = '.';` for a char and "" for a string.

Comment: `continue` is a keyword in C++. You may not use it as an identifier. The variable `int continue;` is not allowed

Answer (score 3):

A few mistakes:

1. `continue` is a keyword. I renamed it to `cont`
2. Double quotes `"."` is for strings. Chars constants are surrounded by single quotes as `'.'`.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string number;

    cout<<"Insert number";
    cin>>number;
    int cont = 0; 
    int integer;
    bool first = false;
    bool primo = false;
    while(cont >= 0){
        if(primo == false){
            integer = number[cont];
            first = true;
            cont++;
        }
        else{
            char dot = '.'; //line 21
            char comma = '.';
            char check = number[cont];
            if((check == comma) or (check == dot)){
                cont = -1;
            }
            else{
                int encapsulation = number[cont];
                integer = (integer*10)+encapsulation;
                cont++;
            }


        }


    }
    cout<<integer;

    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Tvz3MKxx7

Comment: Thanks, the first error of continue is an error of translate, because i writed my program in my language and next i have translate all to english and the name of the variable is change to "continue. The second mistake is my error, thanks for helped me.